# Read Connection Properties from Properties file for JNDI

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I've setup JNDI connection pool in server.xml which is accessible from my webapps. And everything works fine. But the connection pool properties are defined in-line in server.xml

```
<Resource name="_jdbc/kpdB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="15" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
               username="user1" password="password" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
```

But I would prefer similar to the way how userDatabse (which gives access to tomcat manager) is created from tomcat-users.xml but in my case from properties file. Is there any way to do this( I went through the Factory class which creates the kpDB datsource and it doesn't have pathFile property unlike userDatabse)? And I would also prefer to read the file from class path not from conf directory.